# Python - removing an element from a list if it similar to another element

Tags: list

This sounds simple enough but I'm having trouble with it. I have a list with some values, some of which may be similar. If two or more values are similar to one another, I want to remove all but one of those values. e.g. for list a,

a = [10, 45, 48, 120]

Say I wanted to remove a value if it is similar to another by a magnitude of 5. In this case I would therefore want to remove either 45 or 48, it does not matter which. I can envisage finding the absolute difference between each element and every other element, i.e. looping through the list with itself, and creating a new list based on the differences between each element and every other element, e.g.

```
import copy
a = [10,45,48,120]
a_new=[]

for val in a:
    for val_ in a:
        dif = abs(val-val_)
        if dif == 0:
            a_new.append(val_)
        elif dif > 5:
            a_new.append(val_)
    a=copy.deepcopy(a_new)
    a_new=[]
```

Here I try to feed the result back into the loop but I don't get the result I want. I get:

```
a
[10,120]
```

What I want is:

```
a
[10,45,120]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inspecting the values while the code executes, we can see that when val = 45 and val_ = 48, 48 isn't added to a_new. Then when val = 48, a doesn't contain 48, so 48 is never appended to a_new, and 48-45 < 3, so 45 isn't appended to a_new either.

```
import copy
a = [10,45,48,120]
a_new=[]

for val in a:
    print('outer loop: a: {}'.format(a))
    for val_ in a:
        dif = abs(val-val_)
        if dif == 0:
            a_new.append(val_)
        elif dif > 5:
            a_new.append(val_)
        print('val: {:3d}, val_: {:3d}, dif: {:3d}, a: {}, a_new: {}'.format(val, val_, dif, a, a_new))
    a=copy.deepcopy(a_new)
    a_new=[]

outer loop: a: [10, 45, 48, 120]
val:  10, val_:  10, dif:   0, a: [10, 45, 48, 120], a_new: [10]
val:  10, val_:  45, dif:  35, a: [10, 45, 48, 120], a_new: [10, 45]
val:  10, val_:  48, dif:  38, a: [10, 45, 48, 120], a_new: [10, 45, 48]
val:  10, val_: 120, dif: 110, a: [10, 45, 48, 120], a_new: [10, 45, 48, 120]
outer loop: a: [10, 45, 48, 120]
val:  45, val_:  10, dif:  35, a: [10, 45, 48, 120], a_new: [10]
val:  45, val_:  45, dif:   0, a: [10, 45, 48, 120], a_new: [10, 45]
val:  45, val_:  48, dif:   3, a: [10, 45, 48, 120], a_new: [10, 45]
val:  45, val_: 120, dif:  75, a: [10, 45, 48, 120], a_new: [10, 45, 120]
outer loop: a: [10, 45, 120]
val:  48, val_:  10, dif:  38, a: [10, 45, 120], a_new: [10]
val:  48, val_:  45, dif:   3, a: [10, 45, 120], a_new: [10]
val:  48, val_: 120, dif:  72, a: [10, 45, 120], a_new: [10, 120]
outer loop: a: [10, 120]
val: 120, val_:  10, dif: 110, a: [10, 120], a_new: [10]
val: 120, val_: 120, dif:   0, a: [10, 120], a_new: [10, 120]
```

Rather than build new lists, you could achieve your goal just by removing values that fail to meet your condition.

```
a = [10,45,48,120]
for val in a:
    for val_ in a[1:]:
        dif = abs(val - val_)
        if dif > 0 and dif <= 5:
            a.remove(val_)
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the .remove() function

Comment: If you'd like to learn about the other list functions, you should check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). Knowing what tools are available makes it a lot easier to make code do what you want.